# Why does function in ng-show clause not keep on getting executed on each digest cycle

Tags: angularjs

I am doing a test (while busy solving a different problem)

I have a div element defined as follows:

```
<div ng-show="myFunction()">
  //some content
</div>
```

In my controller I have the following JavaScript function:

```
 $scope.myFunction = function () {
    console.log("myFunction called");
    return true;
 }
```

I was expecting that in the browser console, when running this code, I will keep on seeing the words "myFunction called" being written over and over and over since I expect the function to be evaluated on each angular digest cycle. But what I am seeing is that it gets called a finite couple of times and then it no longer gets called.

Why is this?

Comment: As @Nicolas said probably there are no digest cycles anymore. You should try this  
$rootScope.$watch(function(){ 

})
It will be called every $digest loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply spoken, because there probably are no digest cycles anymore. Digest cycles are not some kind of "interval-timer" that runs every 50ms forever, but rather they react on page changes/events. This can be button clicks, scroll events, http-requests, etc.

To test this just add a separate button with a function that simply console.logs some stuff, and you will see that your $scope.myFunction() will be called when you press that button

Answer (score 0):

When a `$digest` cycle runs, the watchers are executed to see if the scope models have changed

$digest cycle/loop keeps looping until there are no more model changes, or it hits the max loop count of 10.

In your case, no model is getting updated at a certain point.

So digest cycle will execute for a finite time(atleast two times), thereofore `"myFunction called"` will be seen for a finite time